# Google omniauth doesn't recognize path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I have problem with **omniauth-google-oath2** gem.

My code:

**devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'app_id','secret'
```

**omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
def google_oauth2
   auth = env["omniauth.auth"]

   @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user) 
   if @user.persisted?
     flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
     sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
   else
     session["devise.google_uid"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
end
```

I also provide method for **find_for_google_oauth2** in my user.rb model.
In my html.erb I wrote:

```
<%= link_to "With Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
```

And in the end I have this error: **No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:google_oauth2, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:provider]**

Where is my mistake?
Thanks for any advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was stupid :)
I just restarted my local rails server and everything working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Check the user model for

```
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]
```

it's probably missing or wrong.